# Showing upload progress while sending an eMail with PHP

Tags: php, html, phpmailer, dropzone.js

I try to implement dropzone.js combined with other form fields to allow users to send an email to a specific recipient. I need the following behavior:

1. The user fills out the form
2. The user drags images into the dropzone. The autoProcessQueue is set to false.
3. The user submits the form
4. The image upload starts. **Here I need an upload progress indicator**. Then the form submits and the email is sending.

I'm asking first of all regarding the progress indicator. Is it possible to show an image upload progress while sending an email with PHP mail?

Thanks in advance for your anwers!

Comment: The upload happens from your browser to your server. Sending the email happens after that, when the server has received the request. So the upload and the progress bar has nothing to do with sending an email. The upload doesn't happen _while_ you're sending the email, it happens _before_ it. The two things are unrelated. If you're using Ajax to send the request from the browser, you can have a progress bar to monitor that. There are a lot of existing examples online, I would think.

Comment: Great. Thank you.